SwiftUI TextField VoiceOver
How can I read the input value of swiftui textfield with voice over.
I have tried with accessibilityLabel and accessibilityValue, but none are working as expected.
I want when the user enter number 1, it will read as 1. And
when the user enter another number 5 in same textfield, I would like to read as 15. Is that possible with swiftui?
